# Flyway migration during ear deployment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, flyway

We would love it if Flyway could migrate our database during deployment of an `.ear` artifact (JBoss 4.2). It should abort if anything goes wrong.

Flyway with `mvn flyway:migrate` works, but for continuous integration and production environments (and maybe others that download new SNAPSHOTS) it would be great to have the DB migrations bundled with the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**API**](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/api) is your friend. Integrate it in a component that **runs on startup**, such as a servlet. Bundle your migrations with the EAR, and you're good to go. In case the **migration fails**, Flyway will throw an **exception** which, if left uncaught, will prevent the application from starting.

Comment: Ok, with a MBean it works :) But we need [Issue 129](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/issues/detail?id=129) to be fixed to use Flyway with JTA Transactions.